# Text will not wrap around image

Tags: css, image, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap my text around an image and for some reason it is not.

[image: Image showing what it looks like]
.

***CSS:***

```
.historyimage {
   float: right;
   margin-top: 260px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe you have `overflow:hidden` or something like that. Can you provide all the HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Where's your code? And where exactly do you want the image to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the first paragraph of the *History* block, that space is taken by the `margin-top` of your image. So the first paragraph cannot use that space.

If you want *only* your **second** paragraph to wrap around the image, in your HTML code put:

- your first paragraph
- your image
- your second paragraph

And remove that `margin-top`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html) out... maybe what you need...

**Update**

Try this out...

```
.historyimage {
    float: right;
    top: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container" style="width: 200px;">
    <div id="paragraph1">paragraph 1 text</div>
    <div id="image" style="float: right; width: 50px;">testing testing testing</div> <!-- you would put your image here. float this to the right, no margin -->
    <div id="paragraph2">paragraph 2 text paragraph 2 text paragraph 2 text paragraph 2 text paragraph 2 text paragraph 2 text </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the picture positioned to the bottom of the text, the simplest way is to insert the img code in that place, where you wish the image to be shown.

You can check http://jsfiddle.net/qh4br/1/ for more info on the position of the image.

Sorry for improper use of stakoverflow, this is my first entry... The good version of the code is in the jsfidle page...

```
<div class="right-side">
 Nullam consectetur, elit sit amet interdum lobortis, urna sapien eleifend arcu, at imperdiet est lacus a neque.
 <img src="http://image1.masterfile.com/em_w/00/60/67/700-00606730w.jpg" width="50" />
Nam blandit mi tortor. Nullam pellentesque facilisis leo in aliquet. Nullam consectetur orci eu ligula laoreet molestie. Nam quis augue enim, ut euismod enim. Integer sit amet consectetur felis. Nam turpis lorem, dictum vel semper ac, rhoncus in metus. 
</div>
```